# How can I grant a java app packaged with jpackage full disk access on a mac?

Tags: java, macos, jpackage, full-disk-access

I've created a java app that's packaged with `jpackage`.  Compiled and packaged with AdoptOpenJDK 14.

After installing on a mac, it needs full disk access to copy files to the `/Application` directory.

Unfortunately, I simply cannot figure out how to do so.  Granting full disk access to the app does not seem to make any difference.

Using `jpackage` is not important.  It just looked like the simplest way to get it done.  I'm happy to package it using something else as long as it's possible for it to get full disk access.